# Electrical and Thermal conductivity of electrum alloys

Tags: conductivity, alloy, thermal-conductivity

I have tried to search for this to little effect - I am trying to find electrical and thermal conductivity values for Electrum (a gold and silver alloy). Most sites mention the values depend on the percentage of gold and silver in the alloy, but provide no actual figures.

Is there a table out there that shows approximate electrical and thermal conductivity for electrum under different amounts of component metals in the alloy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reference may be a good place to get started:

Thermoelectric power and thermal conductivity in the silver-gold alloy system from 3-300°K

https://doi.org/10.1080/14786437008228219

Comment: You should elaborate.